# ui-view shows data on first click of a tab but fails to load the same data on subsequent clicks

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angular 1.5.I am trying to load two templates called roles.html and applications.html. The page get loaded on first click of applications tab or roles tab in nav-bar,but fails on subsequent clicks. My html code is as follows:
                    
                    Applications

Roles

```
              <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="applications" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                  <h3>Applications</h3>
                  <p>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div ui-view="applications"></div>
                    </div>
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div id="entitlements" class="tab-pane fade">
                  <h3>Entitlements</h3>
                  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="roles" class="tab-pane fade">
                  <h3>Roles</h3>
                  <p> 
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div ui-view="roles"></div>
                    </div>
                 </p>
                </div>
              </div>
```

My routes include:

```
        .state('app.userDetails.access',{
        views: {
            'roles': {
                templateUrl: '/app/components/Profile/Roles/roles.html'
            }
            ,
             'applications': {
                templateUrl: '/app/components/Profile/Applications/applications.html'
             }
        }
    })
```